# Windows command for memory utilization % for particular service

Tags: windows, memory, command, percentage, utilization

Use wmic to capture the percentage of cpu usage for a specific service, but wish the same to determine my memory usage,  is it possible to add the same line ?:

> wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get
>   Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:w3wp

Or it needs to be in a different line? 
command with which I can make that query?

Tks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows CMD prompt,

tasklist /fi "services eq ServiceName"

Put your service name in 'ServiceName'

I am not sure if this is what you are asking.